# Swift - Calling a function within an initializer and defining it outside

Tags: swift, function, initialization

I am new to Swift and having some trouble understanding the following lines of code, occurring for a subclass of UITabBar:

```html
override init(frame: CGRect) {
  super.init(frame: frame)
  customInit()
  }
  
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  customInit()
  }

func customInit(){
  self.tintColor = .white
  self.barTintColor = .white
  self.backgroundColor = .white
  }
```

Sorry if this might seem like a stupid question, but knowing that functions must be defined before being called, and properties within an initializer should be before the "super.init", I am wondering what the two customInit() calls are located where they are?

Again, I am new to Swift and really trying to understand how this is working, but have not found any suitable answers anywhere.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Functions don't need to be defined **before** being called; they need to be available when called.

Answer (score 0):

#### You have *Two* options to use your custom class e.g, `CustomTabBar`,

1. Instantiate this class in code
2. Use it in Storyboard

So There are two types of initializers:

1. `init(frame: CGRect)`, that will be called if you initialized this class from code e.g, `CustomTabBar(frame: CGRect(.zero))`
2. `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, that will be called automatically if you used this custom class in Storyboard.

#### why he write the code in a separate func outside the init?

To not duplicate this code in both init methods.

#### initializer should be before the "super.init?

It depends, if you need to call super first or your implementation first, and I see you only changing colors so you need it to be initialized first to manage to change its colors and styles.